# Can I use scaffold boards butted side by side instead of rafters for a flat roof?

Tags: structural, roofing, span-tables

The thickness of a scaffold board is 35mm and so laying the boards side by side (just like you would see on scaffolding) instead of using 4 by 2's will create an extra  60mm of much needed headroom under a section of my garage flat Roof. It would be a permanent installation. The boards would then be sheathed with 18mm ply and possibly edpm roofing material.

The area I wish to cover with said boards would be less than 4 square meters and the span lengths would range from 1.4m to 2.2m. All 4 sides to this area would be supported - ie. 3 walls and a beam. My thinking is that it might even be stronger than using 4 by 2's at 400 centres.

Is there any reason you can think of why using scaffolds wouldn't work?

Comment: I'm struggling a bit with your terminology. "Butted" usually means end-to-end contact. I don't think that's what you mean here. You're talking about doubled rafters of a lesser height, right? What are the actual dimensions of the total rafter cross-section in each scenario?

Comment: @isherwood.  Thanks for your reply. I've edited my question to make it a little clearer. So instead of using 4 by 2's at 400 centres I would be using scaffold boards side by side  (with no gaps) (just as a scaffolder would lay them down on his job). Nothing with doubled rafters. So instead of a 4" high rafter I would only have 35mm scaffold boards.

Comment: A photo of the area would really help. It sounds like you want to lay the boards flat, which usually doesn't work well due to stiffness issues, but if the spans are short enough it might.

Comment: @isherwood   A photo is impractical for me right now but I think you've got it. Yes - boards just lying flat like on a scaffold platform. So, say 4 by 2's at 400 centres - 3 by 2's at 300 centres - 2 by2's at 100 centres - OR -scaffold boards butted side by side with no gaps.

Comment: Scaffold decking usually is really not much of a load bearing thing ok for a person but for a structure? A photo would help if impractical it would still help with the scope of work.